# Docker Slimframework MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

i'm new to docker and slimframework, i'm trying to make a docker file or docker-compose file that when i send to someone else they can run and have my sql db running with the tables already created i dont know if this is right but i get an error.

dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-apache
COPY apache2.conf /etc/apache2
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libpng-dev curl libcurl4-openssl-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gd curl

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN service apache2 restart
```

this is my docker-compose

```
version: '2'

volumes:
    logs:
        driver: local

services:
    db-mysql:
      image: mysql:5
      ports:
        - "3307:3306"
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: path
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    slim:
        image: php:7-alpine
        working_dir: /var/www
        command: php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public
        environment:
            docker: "true"
        depends_on:
          - db-mysql
        ports:
            - 80:8080
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www
            - logs:/var/www/logs
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like the PHP image you're using lacks of the MySQL extension. Either choose an image containing the required extensions or build your own image with the required extensions installed.

Comment: ok how do i do that? I add this to my dockerfile

Comment: Can you first confirm that the extension is missing or not?

Comment: well it works without docker, and i add those lines to my dockerfile and i check the phpinfo() and i see pdo

Comment: But no "PDO Driver for MySQL".

Comment: oh so how can i fix this? cos i dont know what to do

Comment: You need to create your own Dockerfile and manually install it.

Comment: please look at my dockerfile and tell me what i am missing, cos i ran this after the dockerfile docker-compose up -d --build

Comment: Put your Dockerfile in the same directory of docker-compose.yml. Change this line `image: php:7-alpine` to `build: .`. And run `docker-compose up`.

Comment: ok trying that now, I have another question, how do i create the db with tables when i run it without doing it manually

Comment: Use a volume to persist and share the db, instead of creating it every time.

Comment: i'm not sure how is this the correct to do this:
volume:  "db_create: location of sql.sql"

Comment: No, this is not correct. I mean, to create the database in your host, and mount the db directory to the containers.

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm totally clueless here,
this is what i did,
db-mysql:
      image: mysql
      restart: always
      ports:
        - "3307:3306"
      volumes:
        - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: path
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: path
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: root

Comment: I am sending the files to someone else to run on their machine, if i create it on my host how will the person run it

Comment: Oh I see. Then you can import your sql file during image building.

Comment: ok how can I do that?

Comment: See the `Initializing a fresh instance` section in this doc: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167856/discussion-between-yuankun-and-didi).